# Access Database with two different front ends, can't edit when both open

Tags: microsoft-access

I have an Access Database that is split. I have two different front end files. One is designed for trainers to use and one is designed for managers to use. Up until now, I have been running with only the front end for the trainers and have had no issues. I just distributed the Manager front end and discovered that if a manager has their front end open, the trainer cannot edit the database. If the manager closes their front end, then the problem goes away.

Solutions?

Comment: Are you using a table to define roles and the forms are same OR  both forms have a different code to manage the roles?

Comment: Neither. I created two separate front ends. Physically, they're the same, but one is set to open to a particular navigation form and the other to a different one.

Comment: Ok, just make sure that you close all recordsets immediately after use.  If you can share the file, I can have a look.

Comment: Not sure how to share the file on here.